Thriller with female psychiatrist and male criminal who can escape handcuffs
I am looking for a movie or a television show (crime/drama/thriller) featuring a dark-haired female psychiatrist or psychologist who interviews or interrogates a male criminal. He has the ability to dislocate some aspect of his hands escape handcuffs.
I only remember two scenes: 

one where they are sitting in an interrogation room and he takes of the cuffs and touches her legs under the table.
one where the criminal is at her house and a male detective battles him and handcuffs him to some pipe in the basement and tells her upstairs that he cuffed him, while she realizes that will not be enough.

The show was English-speaking, likely from the US, UK or Canada. Probably later than 1990, the three characters mentioned were white.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Wild guess Oxygen (1999)?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0160620/
